# How can we apply animations.css to GWT widgets.?

Tags: html, css, animation, gwt, gwt-animation

I am working with GWT and trying to apply transition effects like slideUp,slideDown etc. using animation.css

I have linked animation.css in html file like,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
```

and also included a script as,

```
<script  type="text/javascript src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

I have applied this animation.css class directly to my panel or widget as,

```
        myPanel.addStyleName("slideInDown");
```

where "slideInDown" is a class name from animation.css,
but the effects are not getting applied to that myPanel.
Can someone help what can be the issue in above case.?

Answer (score 0):

I have just changed the way I added a style name to myPanel as,

```
        myPanel.addStyleName("animated slideInDown");
```

i.e. after adding "animated" before animation.css class name i.e. "slideInDown", the css gets applied to myPanel.